# C++ independent static variable for each object inside a method

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, static-variables

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class CTest
{
public:
    CTest() : c(0)
    {}
    void Method1()
    {
        c++;
        std::cout<<"c: "<<c<<std::endl;
    }
private:
    int c;
};

int main()
{
    CTest A,B,C;
    A.Method1();
    B.Method1();
    C.Method1();
    return 0;
}
```

> c: 1
>
> c: 1
>
> c: 1

for each object of this type, the `c` value is different. To avoid name conflict, I am interested to put the `c` variable inside the function since `Method1` is the only place where it is supposed to be used. My concern is how to make it independent for each different object. Is there any built-in C++ solution?

```
#include <iostream>

class CTest
{
public:
    CTest()
    {}
    void Method1()
    {
        static int c=0;
        c++;
        std::cout<<"c: "<<c<<std::endl;
    }
private:
};

int main()
{
    CTest A,B,C;
    A.Method1();
    B.Method1();
    C.Method1();
    return 0;
}
```

> c: 1
>
> c: 2
>
> c: 3

Comment: first of all, why do you want to do that[?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/coding-standards#global-vars) You could put `c` into the class scope, but then, read the first sentence

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov The problem is the scope. I want to put `c` into the method scope. What is `c` in real case has a confusing name and there are a few other methods using very similar names. Renaming them makes the code very confusing. Better to put each variable into scope of its method.

Comment: @ar2015 you probably need to decompose the class into several ones.

Comment: @AntonSavin are you serious? breaking a big class just because of a few short-scope variables?

Comment: @ar2015 Yes, I'm serious. And the fact that the class is big as you say, makes this suggestion even more viable.

Comment: I dont get it. Why not declare c as non-static in your Method1() ?

Comment: @ar2015 [SOLID](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod) principles should be of help to you

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov which of them does apply here?

Comment: I.e. Single Responsibility Principle, in case you want a counter and `CTest`, which should do something other than counting. If you can separate the concerns, you're more likely to come up with a solution that doesn't require static variables

Answer (score 1):

You *could* do this with templates,

```
template <typename int> class CTest
{
    void Method1()
    {
        static int c = 0;
    }
};
```

And instantiate `CTest<1> A;`, `CTest<2> B;` etc, taking care that you use a different `int` each time. That way, you get a different `c` per `<n>`, which is local to `Method1`. But this is quite contrived, will not work if you want to instantiate `CTest`s dynamically, and I don't think I'd use it in production.

Perhaps an approach using the pImpl idiom would be better.

Answer (score 0):

If this is just a naming issue, then you can just use different names:

```
class CTest
{
public:
    void Method1()
    {
        int& c = unique_but_similar_to_something_else;
        c++;
        std::cout << "c: " << c <<std::endl;
    }
private:
    int unique_but_similar_to_something_else;
};
```

This allows your variable to have a correct name within class scope, but a more friendly name within method scope.

Comment: different names are very confusing. A user cant simply find where that variable would be used and why. Why C++ is not supporting such a simple ability?

Comment: @ar2015 Sorry, what is it that C++ does not support?

Comment: supporting independent static variable inside method for each different object

Comment: @ar2015 Yes, but which language does?

Comment: @ar2015 You've just defined `instance variable`. If you were to have many classes, one for each method, then have a master class which inherits from all of them, then I think you've got what you need.

Answer (score -1):

```
class CTest
{
public:
    CTest() : MY__c(0)
    {

    }
    void Method1()
    {
        int& c = MY__c; // now c is of different meaning and doesn't spoil the "c" we want to have no conflicts with...
        c++;
        std::cout << "c: " << c << std::endl;
    }
private:
    int MY__c;
};
```

Comment: This is a class static var. This code will output   1   2   3 exactly as asked.

Comment: @Vladimir I think that the OP was indicating that the second example is exactly wrong and not wanted.